# how to get the list of files without their extensions in a specified directory in Qt

Tags: qt4, qstring, qdir

i want to get all the files that are located in a specified directory but without their extensions at the end .I did this 
Qt Code:

```
QDir myDir(mConfigDirectory);

         filters << "*.ini";
         myDir.setNameFilters(filters);
     list = myDir.entryList ();
    qDebug()<<list;
```

but i can't find the way to separate the name from the extension and get only names?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QFileInfo Class`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) doesn't help in this case? See [`QString QFileInfo::baseName`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#baseName)